# Report all missing numbers in an array of integers (represented in binary)

Tags: algorithm

I recently had a friend report to me that during a job interview he was asked the following question, which seems to be a pretty popular one:

You are given a list `L[1...n]` that contains all the elements from 0 to n except one. The elements of this list are represented in binary `and are not given in any particular order`, and the only operation we can use to access them is to fetch the jth bit of L[i] in constant time.
How can you find the missing number in `O(n)` ?

He was able to answer this question (which I believe has multiple solutions, none of which being too complicated). For example, the following pseudo-code solves the above problem:

`Say all numbers are represented by k bits and set j as the least significant bit (initially the rightmost).

 1. Starting from j, separate all the numbers in L into two sets (S1 containing all numbers that have 1 as its jth bit, and S2 containing all numbers that have 0 in that position).

 2. The smaller of the two sets contains the missing number, recurse on this subset and set j = j-1`

At each iteration we reduce the size of the set by half. So initially we have O(n), followed by O(n/2), O(n/4) ... = `O(n)`

However the follow-up question was: "What if we now have *k* numbers missing in our list L and we wish to report all *k* numbers while still keeping the O(n) complexity and the limitations of the initial problem? How to do?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
bool J[1..n + 1]={false,false...}
int temp;

for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    temp=bitwisecopy of L[i];
    J[temp + 1]=true
}

for(i = 1; i <= n+1; i++)
{
    if(J[i]==false)
       print i + 1;
}
```

Lol thats the jist of it...I think indices may be messed up.

Am I understanding the problem correctly? It wasn't all the clear to me what exactly was meant by the only operation is access the jth bit of L[i].

Comment: What exactly does "bitwisecopy of" do? Remember that at each iteration we are only allowed to fetch a single bit from a given element of L ( I think this also answers your question?)

Comment: Say there are x bits in each element, where x is constant. We can copy all bits in L[i] into a temp variable in constant time. (ie. O(x*1)=O(1)). Bitwise copy just does a for loop over all the bits and does a shift and AND with temp to stick the bits in...or however you want to do that.

Comment: Understood ;) But that would require fetching every bit in L[i] for each of the n elements, resulting in O(xn). The goal is to only fetch a single bit, what would allow for the O(n).

Comment: Still O(n) lol...in your solution to the first problem, you are not fetching only a single bit..you are actually doing O(logx*n) which is still O(n)

Comment: For your solution, if x = n the complexity is O(n^2). The algorithm (not very well described) I posted, does O(1) for each element n. The first run does O(n), the second O(n/2), O(n/4), etc... so total is O(n)

Comment: Lol...haha i think you got me there. was still a fun fight.

Comment: Arguing is always fun... I guess it's worth saying that x will never exceed lg n (you can represent n with lg n bits).

Comment: @user623879 Yep. Although you almost convinced me otherwise for a second lol

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the original problem in O(n) by just doing a linear walk of the array until you find a number that doesn't match the expected value, like so (yes, I know I'm using an array of ints to approximate the array of bits, but the concept is the same):

```
int[] bits = {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
int bitIndex = 0;
for (int num = 1; num < Integer.MAX_VALUE; num++) {
    int numBits = (int) (Math.log(num) / Math.log(2)) + 1;
    int nextNum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < numBits; index++) {
        nextNum = (nextNum << 1) | bits[bitIndex + index]; 
    }
    if (nextNum != num) {
        System.out.println("Missing number:  expected=" + num + ", actual=" + nextNum);
        break;
    }

    bitIndex += numBits;
}
```

If you want to print all of the numbers that are not present in the array while keeping O(n) runtime, just replace the `break;` with `num = nextNum;` to continue checking for the next number.

Though there are some potential problems with this approach.  If multiple consecutive numbers are missing then all bets are off.  Also if the number of bits in `num + 1` is larger than the number of bits in `num`, and `num` is missing from the bit array, then the bit index will be out of alignment with the data.

Of course, if multiple numbers are allowed to be missing, then the problem isn't really solvable.  Consider for example:

`{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}`

It's just as valid in this case to say that I have numbers 1, 3, and 15 as it is to say that I only have 127 or that I have 7 and 15.  When multiple consecutive values are permitted to go missing, the way to parse the bits essentially becomes arbitrary.

So perhaps one way to answer the second question is to read all the bits into a single large integer, and say "you have [very large number], and all the numbers before it are missing".  Then you've produced a valid answer in O(n) time.

Comment: How do you know what the next number? The numbers cannot be assumed to occur in order, and I don't think there are duplicates allowed.

Comment: @user623879 Correct, the numbers are not given in order, otherwise it would be trivial. And there are no duplicates, assume there is something to represent a gap in the array

Comment: @AlexTim - Then why does your original statement of the problem say "You are given a list `L[1...n]` ..."?  That implies that the list is in ascending order, from 1 -> n.  If the order of the list is arbitrary, then you're basically just fishing for bits because there's no way to determine whether or not the number that makes up a given subsequence of bits was actually present in the input dataset that was used to generate the list of bits.

Comment: `L[1...n] that contains all the elements from 0 to n except one` is the full statement, so implicitly you could imagine the numbers being given in any order. Sorry about the misunderstanding though, I will add the post to be specific about the "arbitrary order". As for your second statement, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. The ultra-high-level pseudo-code above does solve the problem.

Comment: @AlexTim - So is `{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}` a valid bit-array in the context of this problem?  As far as I can tell, it is.  If so, then what number(s) are present, what number(s) are missing, and how did you arrive at your results?  I'm also not sold on the pseudo-code, particularly the part about "separate all the numbers in L into two sets".  There are no numbers in L, just an arbitrary sequence of bits.  To get numbers out of L you first need to parse the bits, and you cannot parse the bits to numbers in any reasonable way if their order may be arbitrary.

Comment: Actually, nevermind.  After reading the description again it sounds like L is a list of integers, of which you can only access each integer in the list one bit at a time (which is kind of nonsensical in practice, but I digress).  The way I originally parsed it, L was the list of bits that was created by concatenating the binary values of all of the integers together, with nothing left to delimit one integer from another.  If the elements of L can be accessed as an array of integers, then the "parsing the bits" issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to solve it in the following way:

lets say 2^M is the lowest power of 2 that higher than N:

```
2^M>N,    2^M-1 <= N
```

now go over all the numbers from 1 to 2^M-1 and do bitwise XOR between all the numbers
(since you can only go over bit J each time do it for each digis separately - it's the same)

the result of all the XORs will be the number you are looking for.

for example: if N=6, and the missing number is 3:

```
M=3 => 2^M-1=7 =>
1 XOR 2 XOR 4 XOR 5 XOR 6 XOR 7 = 3
```

Comment: That is correct if we have a single number missing. However in this case I have k missing number.